# ActionBarSherlock - remove the app icon in the Action View (and other styling issues)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-styles

I have just started using ActionBarSherlock and I'm having some minor styling issues. I don't want the app icon to be displayed on the left side, and that is easily achieved with

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

However in one of the activities I want to have a collapsible action view (a search view). When I set a SearchView as an Action View and drill into it, the app icon appears again. Do you have any idea how to get rid of it?

And another issue is a divider between buttons, how can I set a drawable?

I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623805/actionbarsherlock-stacked-action-bar-styling-issue

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround the icon issue, but I don't really like it. There should be away to make it go away all together in the search mode...

For now, I just set transparent color as an icon drawable:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Still looking for better ideas though!

Comment: It is indeed! Works for now though :-) If you find a better way of doing this, I'll be grateful!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I managed to completely customize the `actionbarsherlock` using my custom layout.

In your `Activity` (which is extending `SherlockFragmentActivity`),

```
mActionBar = getSherlock().getActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
// provide zero dimen drawable for logo icon
mActionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.zero_dimen_icon);

LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
// provide your custom layout here
mActionBar.setCustomView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_content, null),lp);
```

In your drawable folder,

**drawable/zero_dimen_icon.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <size
        android:height="0dp"
        android:width="0dp" >
    </size>

    <solid android:color="#00000000" >
    </solid>

</shape>
```

Works for me, even with the split action bar..

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
  ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    /*  adding action bar on top  */
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);              
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    ab.setTitle("your title");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand this... What is SlideMenu? And also the icon is visible by default and I do NOT want it displayed.

Comment: Sorry, even after your edits it still doesn't make any sense.